# Get Windows Version

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

How can I accurately detect the current Windows operating system on a native (C/C++) project in Visual Studio 2012.3 for operating systems past Windows 8.1?

I've looked in to VersionHelperAPI under MS recommendation, [but this solution only applies to VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538873/cannot-open-include-file-versionhelpers-h-no-such-file-or-directory).

Previously we used `GetVersionEx()`, but I'd like a solution that is more stable and future-proof in a way. It seems like MS is planning to deprecate this in the future.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Add compatibility flags to your manifest file https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/dn481241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx -- then use `VerifyVersionInfo` (preferred) or `GetVersionEx` I don't know what's `GetVersionInfo` in native c/c++

Comment: User [GetVersionEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) to get version, and check if it's version is later than 6.2 , use [version helper api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx) to detect real version, use [GetProcaddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the api function pointer to use so it's will be compiled in older version visual studio or SDK.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - GetVersionEx() is what I meant, apologies.

Comment: @hiitiger - this would work if I had the version helper api, what version of VS are you on?

Comment: @hiitiger won't the Version Helper API give the same results as GetVersionEx?

Comment: @JDługosz Taken from [Microsoft's API documentation online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) "GetVersionEx may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use the Version Helper APIs"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is to include compatibility flags in manifest file:
[Targeting your application for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/dn481241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here are the relevant parts:

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
        <!-- Windows 10 --> 
        <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
        <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
        <!-- Windows Vista -->
        <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
        <!-- Windows 7 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
        <!-- Windows 8 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    </application> 
</compatibility>
```

Without the above tags, when running on Windows 10, `GetVersionEx` and `VerifyVersionInfoW` will see Windows 8

Microsoft insists you should use `VerifyVersionInfoW`, not `GetVersionEx`

There are some helper functions which are not available in earlier VS version. But you may find them on your computer in this directory:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\VersionHelpers.h"
```

Here is what they are (I modified them slightly because they were too long, and tested it for Windows 10, you should double-check for older Windows versions)

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT_NT4      0x0400
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN2K    0x0500
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP    0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WS03     0x0502
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN6     0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA    0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WS08     0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT_LONGHORN 0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7     0x0601
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8     0x0602
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE  0x0603
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10    0x0A00

BOOL IsWinVersionOrGreater(DWORD id, WORD wServicePackMajor)
{
    WORD wMajorVersion = HIBYTE(id);
    WORD wMinorVersion = LOBYTE(id);

    OSVERSIONINFOEXW osvi = { sizeof(osvi), 0, 0, 0, 0,{ 0 }, 0, 0 };
    DWORDLONG const dwlConditionMask =
        VerSetConditionMask(
            VerSetConditionMask(
                VerSetConditionMask(0, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
                VER_MINORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
            VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);

    osvi.dwMajorVersion = wMajorVersion;
    osvi.dwMinorVersion = wMinorVersion;
    osvi.wServicePackMajor = wServicePackMajor;

    return VerifyVersionInfoW(&osvi, VER_MAJORVERSION | VER_MINORVERSION | VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, dwlConditionMask) != FALSE;
}

BOOL IsWindowsXPOrGreater()      {  return IsWinVersionOrGreater(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP, 0);}
BOOL IsWindowsXPSP1OrGreater()   {  return IsWinVersionOrGreater(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP, 1);}
BOOL IsWindowsXPSP2OrGreater()   {  return IsWinVersionOrGreater(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP, 2);}
BOOL IsWindowsXPSP3OrGreater()   {  return IsWinVersionOrGreater(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP, 3);}
BOOL IsWindowsVistaOrGreater()   {  return IsWinVersionOrGreater(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA, 0);}
BOOL IsWindowsVistaSP1OrGreater(){  return IsWinVersionOrGreater(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA, 1);}
BOOL IsWindowsVistaSP2OrGreater(){  return IsWinVersionOrGreater(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA, 2);}
BOOL IsWindows7OrGreater()       {  return IsWinVersionOrGreater(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7,  0);}
BOOL IsWindows7SP1OrGreater()    {  return IsWinVersionOrGreater(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7,  1);}
BOOL IsWindows8OrGreater()       {  return IsWinVersionOrGreater(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8,  0);}
BOOL IsWindows8Point1OrGreater() {  return IsWinVersionOrGreater(_WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE, 0); }
BOOL IsWindows10OrGreater()      {  return IsWinVersionOrGreater(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10, 0); }

BOOL IsWindowsServer()
{
    OSVERSIONINFOEXW osvi = { sizeof(osvi), 0, 0, 0, 0,{ 0 }, 0, 0, 0, VER_NT_WORKSTATION };
    DWORDLONG const dwlConditionMask = VerSetConditionMask(0, VER_PRODUCT_TYPE, VER_EQUAL);
    return !VerifyVersionInfoW(&osvi, VER_PRODUCT_TYPE, dwlConditionMask);
}
```

Comment: I found that our Build server uses Windows Kits\8.0 unfortunately so this solution wouldn't work for those with 8.0. Downloaded WDK 8.1 locally and it works, so I've marked it as best answer.